# Datatables + YADCF + Select2 - default selected data

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery-select2, yadcf

In my project, based on Datatables+YADCF, works with more dropdowns and Select2 fields. 
All data are loaded with Ajax requests.
Okay, and question:

Is possible set default selected values in Select2 field after select value in dropdown?

Or another question: Is possible autofill selected values in select2 field only with Ajax data?

(maybe: 

`{
 key: 1,
 value: car,
 default: true
}`

**UPDATE**

(Server is hosted on heroku (free plan - can be sleep after 30 min of inactivity). Server side is is not ideal, but for this example is probably okay.)

Here is **first example**:

Basic using of Datatables + YADCF library. Above of first column are names in dropdown element. In select2 above of second column are surnames. 
After selecting "name" in dropdown are filtered "surnames" in 2nd column.

https://jsfiddle.net/lukassliacky/fojp91zx/

**2nd example:**

Surname "Winters" is prefilled after run example:

https://jsfiddle.net/lukassliacky/fojp91zx/6/

**Okay, and question:**

In 2nd example are surnames prefilled after refresh with external API function:

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[1, ['Winters']]])
```

Please, is possible load this "prefilled surnames" from server after every request?

For example:
I have countries in dropdown and i need load and prefill regions of selected country in select2 field.

Thank you for you answer.

Comment: it possible to "load the table prefiltered" so it will look as if the filters are pre selected on page load, is it what you looking for ?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. Your suggestion works fine with text search fields, but i need set default values for multiselect field (Select2). 
Please, is possible set default values for multiselect field? Thank you.
Lukas.

Comment: as to prefill filter, you can try calling yadcf init with data property filled with your relevant data for the filter, read more in docs https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/ee1dc1abb1a406413a486a960ba46ae47e15f1e4/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `yadcf.exFilterColumn` method, see example

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [
  [0, ['Some Data 1', 'Some Data 2']]
]);
```

> for pre filtering multi select filter you should use array with values
>   (or an array with single value)

[read more in the docs](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/933e77c612bf33f68933cb4413b4c3650929ed51/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L317)

Comment: Daniel, i have one question: Its possible load this values/data over Ajax? I need show prefilled values after every filter action.
I found your answer here: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/122
but it's information from 2014. I suppose, that it's outdated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed scenario

Comment: I have two forms: first dropdown (one choice) and second Selelect2 (multiselect). 
Values in second field (select2) i must prefilling with values according first dropdown.
Or otherwise: i must load current values for select2 after every change in dropdown.

Comment: but yadcf filters should be based / synced with column data, please provide a clear test case page jsfiddle /etc will be good

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry for late response. I inserted jsfiddle examples in my first question.